# where is MIB for speed fan?

Tags: networking, snmp, mib, cpu-speed

I'm learning SNMP and applying it for hobby. So I was going to use **speed fan** to monitor my pc's temp. well, install was done successfully and it shows temps very well. And for SNMP, I installed sfsnmp.

Now.. Problem is ..

## Where is MIB for speed fan(sfsnmp)?

everybody said that it's OID is `1.3.6.1.4.1.30503`. But my SNMPB viewer cannot show it.

[image]
What should I do? guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of the "folder" 1.3.6.1.4.1. is the enterprise section of the MIB structure you wont find specific values here, what you will find here are more folders and in these folders you will find the specific value you are searching for.

In your case 30503 is the OID number of your folder which you cant see because you dont have the MIB file for this.

http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.html

If you look in this link you will find that 30503 corresponds to this http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.30503.html which is:

```
Used for various utilities from Bastart Code (http://code.bastart.eu.org/) e.g. the SpeedFan SNMP Extension
```

Sadly the URL shows a dead page, but you can probably find a mibfile with this name to use.

Other options you have avaliable to you is to just run a walk with this OID on your motherboard, you will probably get a LOT of data back but you might find out fanspeed values somewhere if you compare the numbers while chaning the fanspeed in another program.